# Running Excel Macro (Button Click) using Bat script

Tags: excel, batch-file, command-line-arguments, batch-processing, vba

I have written an excel Macro, that runs on a button click in Excel.

I want to run the same macro using bat script, i.e. I want to open the excel and click the Button using bat scripting.

I have succeeded in opening the excel sheet but I am unable to run the VBA code(i.e. Click the Button)

I have written the VBA code in following function

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
...
...
End Sub
```

I have tried the following code for bat script-

```
Start G:\Excel\test.xlsm
Run(CommandButton1_Click)
Pause
```

Thanking In anticipation

Comment: Is it just that you want this `Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()` to be ran as soon as the Excel workbook is opened?

Comment: Yes Right. Your comment helped me in sloving the problem. I called **CommandButton1_Click()** function as soon as I open the worksheet. Its working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend that you just add the following Sub:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
   Call CommandButton1_Click
End Sub
```

This will run your CommandButton1_Click as soon as the workbook opens.